# Ajax.BeginForm - Displaying Validation Errors

Tags: validation, ajax.beginform

Using the MVC project template in VS2008 (out of the box) I noticed the following:

1. Here is how the Register.aspx form is specified.

   ```
   <% using (Html.BeginForm()) { %>
   ```
2. Selecting the Register button without supplying any account info shows this.   Account creation was unsuccessful. Please correct the errors and try again.

   • You must specify a username.
      • You must specify an email address.
      • You must specify a password of 6 or more characters.
3. I changed the Register.aspx form to this.

   ```
   <% using (Ajax.BeginForm("Register", new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "Post" })) { %>
   ```
4. Selecting the Register button without supplying an account info shows no errors.

Question:  How do I get the error text to display when using Ajax.BeginForm ?

Answer (score 14):

To successfully apply ajax form submission you will have to modify the Register action and the views. By default, in case of error, this action just returns the associated register.aspx view. The first step would be to put the validation summary inside a partial user control:

ValidationSummary.ascx:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl" %>
<%= Html.ValidationSummary("Account creation was unsuccessful. Please correct the errors and try again.") %>
```

Then you include this partial inside the Register.aspx view:

```
<div id="validationSummary">
    <% Html.RenderPartial("ValidationSummary"); %>
</div>

<% using (Ajax.BeginForm(new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST", UpdateTargetId = "validationSummary" })) { %>
    FORM CODE HERE
<% } %>
```

And finally you modify the Register action:

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
public ActionResult Register(string userName, string email, string password, string confirmPassword)
{
    // ... skipped content for clarity

    // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
    if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
    {
        // If an ajax request was made return only the validation errors 
        // instead of the whole page
        return PartialView("ValidationSummary");
    }
    else
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

In case the registration succeeds by default the Register action just redirects to Home/Index. You will have to modify this bit as well, because as you are performing an ajax request the redirection won't work. The same way you could test if you are invoking the action asynchronously and return some text that will indicate that the registration was successful. This text will be displayed inside the same `div` as the validation errors.

---

UPDATE:

> One final question - Instead of the
>   bullet list of error messages, how do
>   I get each controls error message to
>   render next to the control using the
>   Html.ValidationMessage("....") method
>   ?

In order to achieve this you need to put the contents of your form inside a partial view:

```
<% using (Ajax.BeginForm(
    "register", 
    null, 
    new AjaxOptions { 
        HttpMethod = "POST", 
        UpdateTargetId = "myForm" 
    }, 
    new { 
        id = "myForm" 
    })) { %>
     <% Html.RenderPartial("RegisterForm"); %>
<% } %>
```

And in your register action render the correct partial:

```
if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
{
    return PartialView("RegisterForm");
}
else
{
    return View();
}
```